# Grouping List by the last Char

Tags: c#, list, lambda, group-by

[alt text http://barbarosalp.com/questions/list.png](http://barbarosalp.com/questions/list.png)

Hi,

As you can see on the picture above i have a List "keys" filled with Request.Form.AllKeys which a key starts with "txt".

I want to group them by their last id, for example

```
[0] "txtTitle:2" "txtDescription:2"
[1] "txtTitle:3" "txtDescription:3"
```

How can i achive this with lambda expression.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = keys.GroupBy(e=>e.Split(':').Last());
```